# sort an array within a json array with jolt

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, transformation, jolt

I have an array that is used in an application to show some files that need to be ordered.

I wonder if it is possible to shake order the most recent "value" of the "Creation date".

we have not achieved it with the array inside an array

This is the entry:

```json
[
  {
    "campos": [
      {
        "nombre_campo": "ID",
        "valor": "1635942768793"
      },
      {
        "nombre_campo": "Fecha creación",
        "valor": "2021-01-04 09:32:48"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "campos": [
      {
        "nombre_campo": "ID",
        "valor": "1632417779050"
      },
      {
        "nombre_campo": "Fecha creación",
        "valor": "2021-09-23 14:22:59"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would:

```json
[
  {
    "campos": [
      {
        "nombre_campo": "ID",
        "valor": "1632417779050"
      },
      {
        "nombre_campo": "Fecha creación",
        "valor": "2021-09-23 14:22:59"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "campos": [
      {
        "nombre_campo": "ID",
        "valor": "1635942768793"
      },
      {
        "nombre_campo": "Fecha creación",
        "valor": "2021-01-04 09:32:48"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We can use **sort** spec after a manipulation which replaces keys named `campos` with `ID` values through use of `campos[0].valor( eg. &[0].valor - "the valor values within the first indexes" )` within the first **shift** spec, since there's no *descreasing* option for the **sort** spec, but we have the opportunity to get `ID` values which are descreasing while `Fecha creación(eg. Creation date )` values are increasing.

So, consider applying the following specs

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "@(1,&[0].valor)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&.campos"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

[image]